# Why is lua's string pattern matching doing this?

Tags: windows, winapi, lua, lua-patterns

I have an external application which monitors CPU and GPU temperatures...

I am using Lua with the [alien extension](http://alien.luaforge.net/) to grab these values (via [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and to do some pattern matching on these values, effectively extracting the temperature digits out of the string, which by default shows up as something like `CPU   67.875 °C`...
But perhaps I have the wrong idea on how patterns work in LUA (since they don't appear to be exactly like regex)?

The pattern I am using is `[%d]+[.%d+]*` which should match any number between 0 and 100.0, correct?
Yet oddly enough, I am [getting incredibly strange output](http://ideone.com/astDNJ) when values reach around 56.5 degrees *(see link)*.

Why is this happening?
And how can I extract the correct floating point values (as a string) between 0 and 100 in the format of `XYY.ZZZ`, where `X` is not optional, `Y` is optional, and `.` is optional unless `Z` exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing the effect of accumulated rounding errors because 0.16 cannot be precisely represented in floating point. The code below performs better:

```
local n = 0
while n < 10000 do
    local s = tostring(n/100)
    local t = s:match("[%d]+[.%d+]*")
    print(t)
    n = n + 16
end
```

Now, to your question, try the simpler pattern below:

```
s="CPU 67.875 °C"
print(s:match("CPU +(.-) +"))
```

Comment: Okay, I figured it was just a mathematical race condition of sorts... But this still doesn't explain _why_ it decides to go crazy halfway, and continues onward to infinity.

Comment: @RectangleEquals, see [The Floating-Point Guide - What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: @RectangleEquals: Note that, while your pattern has nothing to do with this (you could just print out `s` and see the same thing), your pattern is also wrong. You need to escape the `.`, and only check for *one* of them in the second clause: `[%d]+%.?[%d]*`. Otherwise, you could parse "10aaaaa4bdcedd5" just as easily as "10.45".

Comment: @NicolBolas, you don't need to escape `.` in classes.

Comment: @lhf: Sure you do. `.` means to [match any character](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1). If you want to match actual ".", you have to escape it.

Comment: @NicolBolas, have you tried it? `s="10aaaaa4bdcedd5"; p="[%d]+[.%d+]*"; print(s:match(p))`

Comment: @NicolBolas, you need to escape `.` in *patterns* but not in *classes*. OTOH, it does no harm.

Comment: @NicolBolas - 1) In most regex flavors metacharacters `may not` or even `must not` be escaped in classes. 2) I guess, lhf is one of the three men on [that](http://www.lua.org/authors.html) photo, namely, the most intelligent-looking one  :-)  Do you really want to argue with him about how Lua works?

Comment: @lhf Your example seems to work, and I after a simple `string.format("%3.3f", t)` I can live with the output. Thank you!